# Hibernate Panache UpdateTimeStamp doesn't seem to work

Tags: hibernate, kotlin, quarkus, quarkus-panache

I'm writing some tests for my repository, and it seems my @UpdateTimestamp doesn't work. When I first fetch the entity, and then update it, the timestamp doesn't change. Does anyone know why this is?

I'm using Quarkus, Kotlin, and Hibernate Panache.

Comment: Maybe dump question but do you modify the entity? Meaning using setters to change eg the name? Because just saving the entity without changing it won’t change the timestamp

Answer (score 0):

you can use @PostLoad on entitylistener

```
@PostLoad
public void onPostLoad(Entity entity) {
    entity.setUpdatedBy(jsonWebToken.getClaim(Claims.email));
}

@EntityListeners(AuditListener.class)
@Entity
```